# Is it legal to pretend to be the British monarch?

Tags: united-kingdom

Is it legal for John Doe, in the UK, to claim to be king of the UK and insist on being called His Majesty King John II?

I'm not asking about impersonating the actual monarch (e.g. claiming to be King Charles III), but keeping one's real name but calling oneself King or Queen.

Comment: Wasn't there an Emperor of San Francisco ... or similar? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett There was indeed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Norton But the issue was a bit different than it would be in the U.K. where there actually is a king.

Comment: Idi Amin, once the leader of Uganda, called himself "King of Scotland". Not because he actually claimed it but to rub the British up the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not versed in the law, but I would think in many places it's illegal to pretend to be **anyone** else, not only the British monarch. It being false impersonation

Comment: @Ivo : yes, but in this case it was not about someone pretending to be one specific other person.

Comment: Don't forget Arthur Pendragon, King Of The Britains. He currently lives in Salisbury.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Uther_Pendragon.

Comment: Isn't there some Jacobite descendant who styles himself "King Francis" or some such?

Comment: In addition to the examples noted by [David Siegel](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/17500/david-siegel), there is also the [King of Kowloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsang_Tsou_Choi).

Comment: [A woman seems to be getting away](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/23/queen-of-canada-qanon-rise-conspiracy-alarm) with claiming to be queen of canada, which is also claimed by the british monarch.

Comment: I am the Prince of Wales.

Comment: @Neil - did you mean 'King of the **Britons**?

Comment: @Ivo There are often separate crimes with different penalties depending on who you're impersonating. E.g. impersonating a police officer is different from general impersonation.

Comment: i hope not, or I might get beheaded when I jokingly reply that my personal pronoun is "your majesty"!

Comment: What do you mean by "pretend"? I'm sure if you dressed up as a king or queen for Hallowe'en you won't have the SAS breaking down your door...

Comment: @Cicero I am a Nigerian Prince. That pays more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It depends where one does this. In the UK, I believe it is a crime to falsely claim to be the monarch. [Lady Jane Grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Jane_Grey) was beheaded for doing so. The charge was treason.

In any other places it is probably not a crime, but **might** be viewed as evidence of insanity.

A comment mentioned [Emperor Norton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Norton) who lived from 1818 to 1880, largely in the US city of San Francisco. He proclaimed himself "Emperor of the United States". He was treated as a piece of "local color", not as a criminal. According to the Wikipedia article on him (linked above):

> Norton had no formal political power; nevertheless, he was treated deferentially in San Francisco, and currency issued in his name was honored in the establishments that he frequented. Some considered him insane or eccentric, but citizens of San Francisco celebrated his imperial presence and his proclamations, such as his order that the United States Congress be dissolved by force and his numerous decrees calling for the construction of a bridge and tunnel crossing San Francisco Bay to connect San Francisco with Oakland. Though Norton received many favors from the city, merchants also capitalized on his notoriety by selling souvenirs bearing his name.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139339/discussion-on-answer-by-david-siegel-is-it-legal-to-pretend-to-be-the-british-mo).

Comment: If calling yourself "the King of England" was considered an insult to King Charles |||, then it _might_ be illegal in Germany.

Comment: Lady Jane Grey was likely mislead and arguably, was queen for several days.

Comment: There is the legendary prank by Hape Kerkeling, now more than 30 years ago, when he pretended to be Queen Beatrix of the Netherlands and [drove with a limousine to the entrance of the presidential residence](https://de-de.facebook.com/einsfuereuch/videos/total-normal/166826018278496/) to have a "lekker" lunch with him. Allegedly he wondered whether it was treason or *lèse-majesty* cor trespassing but I don't think he was ever charged. Of course being a celebrity sometimes helps.

Comment: Hmmm. Emperor Norton reminds me of someone orange.